# Regular expression to select some characters except the ones inside the double quotation

Tags: regex

I have a sentence like this :

```
Number; Year; "43643-25262.123; ABC2322"; Project is supported by the Organization X ("No. 11AZD121"); adress; "12344;123131; 3859563";;; employees
```

How I can write a regular expression to select semicolons (`;`) except the ones that are in the fields with double quotation (`"`)? So I expect the regular expression to find all the semi colons except the ones which are in `"43643-25262.123; ABC2322"` and `"12344;123131; 3859563"`.

Comment: [`;(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/mPhHgZ/1) assuming quotes are balanced and unescaped.

Comment: @anubhava thank you, but your proposed regexp doesn't work when I test it in Visual Studio Code

Comment: (!?)(“.*?”;*) this should work

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
input = Number; Year; "43643-25262.123; ABC2322"; Project is supported by the Organization X ("No. 11AZD121"); adress; "12344;123131; 3859563";;; employees

pattern= (!?)(“.*?”;*)

input.match(pattern)

//output Number; Year;  Project is supported by the Organization X (); adress;  employees
```

Comment: thank you, what programming language have did you try this?

Comment: It’s just a pseudo code not any language I tried that regex on https://regex101.com and it works

Comment: I just tried it in Visual Studio Code, but it didn't work

Comment: That should work try it on regex101 it’s working for me

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like what you have is CSV (comma-separated values) string that is using semicolons instead of commas.  I would see if there is existing code you could use in your programming language of choice that handles CSV files and can handle semicolons as a separator.

For instance, in Perl's [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) module, you can call the `->sep_set` module to define the separators to use.

Dealing with these separators and quoting is a common problem that's been well-solved and is also fraught with weird corner cases.  If you can get an existing tool to do it for you, rather than trying to make up a regex to do it, that would probably be the safest.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes this is supposed to be a comma-separated file, but instead of comma, semi-colon has been used. But the real problem is that, there are some random extra semi-colon in each record which has gave me hard time and now I am trying to solve it by this regexp approach